# Dynamic three variable width column HTML layout

Tags: html, fixed

I know there are a million similar articles and I have spent hours trying them all to no avail.  I want to be have to have three columns and allow each column to take as much space as necessary but the entire container not to exceed a fixed with (say 500 pixels in this example).  The left column must flush left and the right flush right at all times.  Often the left and/or right column will be empty and the center should use the entire width.

I can certainly accomplish this with a table with fixed layout or divs with fixed sizes, however, I want to be able to dynamically reuse the same containers to display one, two, or three columns of data and use then entire width available.  I can absolutely allow for a fixed with on the contents in col 1 and column 3, though it does not seem to help.

Here is an example:

```
<div style="width:500px;background:#ff0000;max-width:500px;">
    <div style="background:#00ff00;float:left;display:table-cell;">
          col1
    </div>
    <div style="background:#ff00ff;float:left;display:table-cell;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:elipsis;white-space:nowrap;">
          REALLY LONG DO NOT EXCEED 500 - WIDTH COL 1 AND COL2 SOMEHOW WOULD BE NICE
    </div>
    <div style="background:#00ffff;display:table-cell;float:right;">
          col3
    </div>
</div>
```

Sorry, cannot show the output of the above since it will not allow me to post an image.

Comment: You can't post an image, but you could link to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)... ?

Comment: So in other words, you want a three column grid, but if one column doesn't have any information in it, then it should hide and the other two columns take up that extra space?

Comment: You may want to think about using a div wrapper around the column divs, because then, you can set the outside div to be 500px, and the inner div columns to just be percentages of that wrapper.

Comment: Should have used jsfiddle.  Thanks to bspy for the suggestions.  I think I need to take the time to further understand [this link](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/holy-grail-no-quirks-mode.htm) which is constantly mentioned for this issue and seems to be the answer after further consideration.

Comment: Actually the link I mentioned does not allow for the content to dictate the width of the side columns - it used fixed sizes.  @bspymaster - you mention using each column as a fixed percentage of the the outer - however, that is exactly what I am trying to avoid.  I do not want to have to set widths for the columns.  I want them to expand to their content which could vary greatly.